# Javascript: create dynamic js based on attribute from JSON read from a DB table

Tags: javascript

I hope someone can help me with some JavaScript that I am stuck on.  I guess I would call this dynamic JavaScript.  Here is what I'm trying to accomplish.

Overview of the app:
This is an entitlements app, where the user selects an application from a drop down that they need to be entitled to.  Once they select the app, the system reads a db record for this app.  In that record, there is JSON that defines what other information needs to be prompted for and the app will dynamically build the prompts and append to the HTML.

1. Read some JSON from a DB table using ajax (this works fine)
2. Using the 'variable' attribute from the JSON, create the following code substituting varname with the name defined in the variable attribute.

Code:

```
$('select[name="varname"]').on('change', function() {        
var varname = $('select[name="varname"]').val(); });
```

JSON

```
{
"prompts": [{
        "id": "1",
        "enabled": "1",
        "required": "1",
        "prompt": "AWS Account Number ",
        "variable": "aws_account_number",
        "type": "select",
        "value_list_type": "table",
        "table_name": "cld_accounts",
        "filter": "filter=accounttype,eq,aws&filter=accountstatus,eq,open&filter=rootaccountowner,eq,sts",
        "order": "order=accountnumber",
        "value_column": "record.accountnumber",
        "dropdown_definition": "'record.accountnumber + \" - \" + record.clientid + \" - \" + record.alias'"

    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "enabled": "1",
        "required": "1",
        "prompt": "Requested Permission ",
        "variable": "permission",
        "type": "select",
        "value_list_type": "table",
        "table_name": "aws_sso_mapping_from_ad",
        "filter": "filter=accountnumber,eq,aws_account_number",
        "order": "order=rolename",
        "value_column": "record.rolename",
        "dropdown_definition": "'record.rolename'"
    }
]}
```

so, everywhere that 'varname' appears in that select function, it needs to be 'aws_account_number' so that this is the code that is generated:

```
$('select[name="aws_account_number"]').on('change', function() {        
var aws_account_number = $('select[name="aws_account_number"]').val(); });
```

Below is my function code.  Right after eval(ssrc1) (I know I shouldn't be using eval) is what I can't get to work.  I have tried eval, string replace, template literals, etc., nothing seems to work.

Maybe there is a better way if anyone has any other suggestions.  Basically what I need after the user completes all the prompts is to be able to send that data to handler that will entitle the user for the app.  The problem is app 1 may have two prompts, app 2 may have four prompts.

```
// Get additional data based on selected application
    $('select[name="application"]').on('change', function() {
        var appId = $('select[name="application"]').val();
        getApplicationConfig(appId);
    });


    function getApplicationConfig(appId) {
        url = "/apiv1/api.php/records/ent_appconfig?filter=id,eq," + appId
        console.log('getting application config, appId: ' + appId);
        webix.ajax().headers({
            "<?php echo $api_header_key?>":"<?php echo $api_header_value?>",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"
        }).get(url).then(function(data){
            app_data = JSON.parse(data.text());

            app_data.data[0].prompts_json.prompts.forEach(generateHTML);

            function generateHTML(item) {
                if ((item.type == 'select') && (item.enabled == '1')) {
                    console.log('generateHTML: ' + JSON.stringify(item));
                    html = gen_html_select(item.variable, item.prompt, item.required);

                    $('#additional_questions').append(html);    // Append generated html to additional_questions div

                    // Select that uses table for options
                    if (item.value_list_type == 'table') {
                        vx = "var1";
                        ssrc1 = '';     // clear the variable
                        ssrc1 = 'url = "' + generateURL(item.table_name, item.filter, item.order) + '"; \
                        webix.ajax().headers({ "<?php echo $api_header_key?>":"<?php echo $api_header_value?>", \
                            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*" \
                        }).get(url).then(function(data){ \
                            app_data = JSON.parse(data.text()); \
                            console.log(app_data.data); \
                            app_data.data.forEach(generateSelectOptions); \
                        });'
                        
                        eval(ssrc1);
                        console.log("url: " + url);
                        window[item.variable] = "TEST123456";
                        console.log('window item.variable: ' + aws_account_number);
                        console.log('wiv: ' + window[item.variable]);

                        ssrc2 = '$(\'select[name="\' + item.variable + \'"]\').on(\'change\', function() { \
                        window[item.variable] = $(\'select[name="\' + item.variable + \'"]\').val(); \
                        console.log(\' accountnumber \' + aws_account_number); \
                        });'

                        console.log('ssrc2: ' + ssrc2);

                        //xxx = eval(ssrc2);
                        //var_dump(ssrc2);
                        //console.log('ssrc2: ' + xxx);

                        // var k = item.variable;
                        // console.log('item_variable: ' + k);
                        // //eval('var ' + k + '= ' + 'david;');
                        // //eval('var ' + k + ' = 10;');
                        // eval('var ' + k + ' = 100;');

                        // console.log('variable: ' + eval('item.variable;'));
                     
                    }   // End select table

                    
                    
                    // Select that uses the app JSON for options
                    if (item.value_list_type == 'list') {
                        console.log("select list");
                        console.log(item.list_values);

                        //app_data2 = JSON.parse(item.list_values);
                        app_data2 = item.list_values;

                        //console.log(app_data2);
                        app_data2.forEach(get_permission);

                        console.log("finished");
                    }   // End select list


                }   // End if item.type = select and item.enabled = 1


                function generateSelectOptions(record) {
                    // Needs to stay in generateHTML function to access the item object
                    option_template = 'newOption = new Option(<DISPLAY>, <VALUE>);' 

                    // Replace placeholders in template with values from app JSON
                    var result = option_template.replace(/<VALUE>/gi, eval(item.value_column));
                    result = result.replace(/<DISPLAY>/gi, eval(item.dropdown_definition));

                    eval(result);
                    aws_account_number.add(newOption, undefined);
                }   // End generateSelectOptions
                
            }   // End generateHTML

            



            $(".select2").select2();

            // $('select[name="aws_account_number"]').on('change', function() {        
            //     var accountnumber = $('select[name="aws_account_number"]').val();
            //     console.log('accountnumber ' + accountnumber);
            // });
           

        }); // End webix ajax call

    }   // End getApplicationConfig
```

Comment: So you are asking how to search/replace text within a string?

Comment: You have your JSON and the desired results but what have you tried?  Please update with your attempt and the one issue you have with it.

Comment: Part of your code `$('select[name="aws_account_number"]').val();` can be `$(this).val();`